# Adding new network

Tags: gnosis, gnosis-safe

I want to add new network to my local safe-react app. I deployed contracts to the new network but how can I use them in my safe-react app. As I understand safe-react fetches networks from config-service or transaction-service. I could not figure it out what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed fetching the network configs from the backend.

Contracts is just one part of the infra. The app also relies on the said backend for indexing transactions on a given chain and for many other functions.

It's totally possible to use the contracts directly, though. E.g. using the [Safe CLI](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli).

Comment: Here some resources if you want to run the services yourself: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/backend/service-architecture, https://github.com/gnosis/safe-infrastructure

Comment: But I want to add network with using config service and transaction service without changing anything on web app. How can I do this?

Comment: @ardaersoy config-service is a Django app, so you just add it via the admin.

Comment: So I can fork and run in my local I can do this change right? If yes in which part do I need to change exactly?

Comment: You would still have to adjust the url of the client gateway in the web app. This can be done via an env variable. See https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/blob/aedc39c4092c10cf73b74611606faa0cbe80473d/src/utils/constants.ts#L44-L48